# How to change character weight in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, character

So i try to make a adventure game and in one point my character need to eat some food and get fatter and fatter, smoothly every second.I've found only one solution in asset store.The MCS(Morph 3D) has this feature.But problem is i don't want to use one of their character.I have my on low-poly 3d character and i want to use this.

This is an example of what i need :
[MCS Morph 3D](https://youtu.be/csQoCBZ4gWA?t=25s)

So where should i start? What should i look in to? Is there simple way to this or is it really hard?

Thanks already :)

Comment: If no need wonderful effect maybe you could send custom value to the shader.You could search how to use shader expand model apprearance.

Comment: @RonTang You don't do that with a shader. Shader can resize a model but that's different than morphing a 3D model

Comment: @Programmer thanks note that.

Answer (score -1):

This would normally be done with a frag/vert shader. You would modify the vertices of the mesh in the stomach area based on some value. This could be done really simply in which the distance of the stomach vertices from some given point located in the character's core would just increase based on your given value. I believe your thoughts are imagining something much prettier than this, but anything else would be much more involved for something that is purely visual. If you are not experienced with shaders, I would highly recommend purchasing a visual shader editor, such as Amplify (ASE) or Shader Forge. They make the jump into shaders **much** easier.